# How do I change the default cursor in leaflet maps?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to modify the default cursor icon when a certain control button is pressed.
Although I was partially successful by using css on the container div, doing this overrides the move cursor state, which is something I do not want. What I mean with this is that the move icon no longer appears while moving through the map (but not when on markers!).

I'd like to know if there is a non-hacky way through the api to achieve special cursor behaviour without redifining everything.

This is what I tried to do, #map is the container div for the leaflet map.

```css
#map[control=pressed] {
    cursor: url('..custom.png');
}
```

Comment: when a control button is disable, any class has been added to the button?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Edit 5.18.2017: Raw CSS and Javascript via Leaflet Framework (recommended)**

I was looking through the source code for [the BoxZoom plugin](https://github.com/gregallensworth/L.Control.BoxZoom) and noticed their approach using [Leaflet's built-in DOM mutators](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#domutil) and wanted to promote it here...this is certainly the best practice.

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hx2yxdc0/14/)

Somewhere in your CSS include a class like this..

```
.leaflet-container.crosshair-cursor-enabled {
    cursor:crosshair;
}
```

When you want to enable crosshairs, do this in your JS..

```
// Assumes your Leaflet map variable is 'map'..
L.DomUtil.addClass(map._container,'crosshair-cursor-enabled');
```

Then, when you want to disable crosshairs, do this in your JS..

```
L.DomUtil.removeClass(map._container,'crosshair-cursor-enabled');
```

---

**Original Answer: Map-level Crosshairs**

@scud42 got me on the right path. You can use JQuery to change the Leaflet map cursor like this:

```
$('.leaflet-container').css('cursor','crosshair');
```

Then later, when you want to reset the map cursor, you can do this:

```
$('.leaflet-container').css('cursor','');
```

---

**Edit 1.21.2016: Per-feature Crosshairs**

You can also enable crosshairs for individual features supporting the `className` option, such as a polygon, or feature vertices, etc.

Here's an example of a draggable vertice that will toggle pointer crosshairs ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hx2yxdc0/)):

```
var svg_html_default = '<div style="margin:0px;padding:0px;height:8px;width:8px;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFFFF;border-width:1px;background-color:#424242"</div>';

var default_icon = L.divIcon({
  html: svg_html_default,
  className: 'leaflet-mouse-marker',
  iconAnchor: [5,5],
  iconSize: [8,8]
});

var m = new L.marker([33.9731003, -80.9968865], {
  icon: default_icon,
  draggable: true,
  opacity: 0.7
}).addTo( map );

m.on("mouseover",function(){$('.leaflet-mouse-marker').css('cursor','crosshair');});

m.on("mouseout",function(){$('.leaflet-mouse-marker').css('cursor','');});
```

Comment: Although it's been a long time obsolete for me, I'm awarding this as the correct answer. Thanks for the jsfiddle for me to corroborate the working behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

Leaflet's styles allow you to change some cursor behavior. Put these in your local CSS to make the change.

```
/* Change cursor when mousing over clickable layer */
.leaflet-clickable {
  cursor: crosshair !important;
}
/* Change cursor when over entire map */
.leaflet-container {
  cursor: help !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Set to crosshair:

```
document.getElementById('map').style.cursor = 'crosshair'
```

Reset it back:

```
document.getElementById('map').style.cursor = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `active` pseudo class.

```
#map:active {
    cursor: url('..custom.png');
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WsmHw/)**

For overriding a cursor you will probably want to use the css3 attribute `user-select: none` so that it doesn't toggle between the text and default cursor when dragging on the element. That implementation is also shown in the JSFiddle.

Comment: I tried following your suggestion, but it seems the api is breaking the pseudo class behaviour. Although, over the map controls it is working (which inconveniently is something I do not want to happen).

Comment: @snowgage It has been so long since the question that I don't even remember. I believe I ended up moving onto something else before resolving this.
Although I'm thinking of going back to the mapping scene soon; if this same issue comes up again and I do find the answer, I'll make sure to post it here

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
// CSS first. Add this to leaflet stylesheet.
.leaflet-interactive.wait-cursor-enabled {
    cursor: wait !important;
}

// JS select from map container and add class to each element
let map = L.map('map');
let els = map.getContainer().querySelectorAll('.leaflet-interactive');
for(let el of els){
   el.classList += ' wait-cursor-enabled'; 
}

//JS remove class once no longer needed
let els = map.getContainer().querySelectorAll('.leaflet-interactive.wait-cursor-enabled');
for(let el of els){
   el.classList.remove("wait-cursor-enabled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.leaflet-container').css('cursor','crosshair');
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) and needed to change the cursor over the map and the polygons on it, based on a bit of state higher up in the app. Changing the cursor for the map itself was simple:

```
map.getContainer().style.cursor = 'crosshair';
```

For the polygons on the map it was not as straightforward. Leaflet polygons take a `className` option, which could be used to override the default `leaflet-interactive` class that sets the cursor to `pointer`. However, I found that `className` was not a dynamic option: re-rendering the polygon did not change the className (see [this github issue](https://github.com/leaflet/leaflet/issues/2662#issue-32642357)).

I use styled-components, so I tried to wrap the Polygon component to override the `cursor` style rule, but this, also, only worked when the Polygon was first created. Eventually, I settled on capturing a reference to the Polygon object:

```
<Polygon ref={(el:any) => this.wrapperRef = el} /* ... */ />
```

and used this to set the cursor style rule on update:

```
componentDidUpdate = () => {
  this.wrapperRef._path.style.cursor = this.props.cursor;
}
```

As discussed in the [aforementioned github issue](https://github.com/leaflet/leaflet/issues/2662#issue-32642357), the property `_path` of the object created by Leaflet can be used to access and override the style.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your rule another selector, that wil also match .leaflet-interactive class

```css
#map[control=pressed],
#map[control=pressed] .leaflet-interactive {
    cursor: url('..custom.png');
}
```

The root problem is with svg-based overlays, wich have inner elements with leaflet-interactive class like

```xml
<svg> <g> <path class="leaflet-interactive">...
```

And it turns out that leaflet's native style
.leaflet-interactive { cursor: pointer; }
has higher specifity inside svg, than even id-based rule from main document.