# How to force the default cursor when hovering over a marker

Tags: leaflet

I would like to force the default cursor instead of the pointer (pointing finger) when hovering over a marker. I have already done this for the map using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106687/how-do-i-change-the-default-cursor-in-leaflet-maps) SO answer, but not sure how to proceed for the pointer when hovering over a marker.

In other words, what is the leaflet css element that controls the cursor type when hovering over a marker?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Load your Leaflet map in your favourite browser.
2. Open your browser [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) (similar for Firefox, Safari…)
3. Open the [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) tool (similar for Chrome, Safari…)
4. Use the ["Pick an element from the page"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Select_an_element) tool and select a marker on the Leaflet map.
   [image: "Pick an element" button icon] (similar for Chrome, Safari…)

[image: "Pick an element" button in DOM inspector tool]

<sub>(images from [MDN wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/UI_Tour) by [Mozilla contributors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/UI_Tour$history), licensed under [CC-BY-SA 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/))</sub>

5. Browse the [CSS pane](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/UI_Tour#CSS_pane) and look for the applicable `cursor` rule.

In your case, you should see:

```css
.leaflet-interactive {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Now you know which CSS class you should override to modify the cursor.

That being said, you can also define your own custom icon and apply a `className` option on it, so that you specify a `cursor` rule on that class, instead of overriding the Leaflet CSS rule. Both options are reasonable, depending on the exact extent of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If there are multiple layers and I want to change the cursor for only one, how to achieve that?

Comment: @Pankaj You should probably assign 1 class per layer. Please open a new question should you need help for an issue that is different from what is described here.