# How do I change the default cursor with ngx-leaflet?

Tags: cursor, leaflet, leaflet.draw, ngx-leaflet

I tried to change to cursor to achieve a fluid integration with leaflet draw shown in this example.

https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/popup.html

When the cursor is over the image it's and open hand. When the cursor is over an drawing it's a pointer.

Unfortunately non of the standard leaflet techniques described here worked.

[How do I change the default cursor in leaflet maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106687/how-do-i-change-the-default-cursor-in-leaflet-maps)

Does someone has an idea how to do it with ngx-leaflet?

Comment: Can you describe the specific problem? When I run the @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw plugin, the cursor is a pointer when it's hovering a drawn element. Are you using ngx-leaflet-draw or just ngx-leaflet? Can you provide some code and/or a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an imageoverlay with the same dimensions, which was stacked behind the tilelayer. I had to set interactive: false inside the imageOverlay