# How to change cursor in Leaflet in R Shiny in Browser

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have an interactive R Markdown document using Shiny, which includes a Leaflet map control. When I run the app locally it is fine, but when I run it in a browser, the cursor changes to a "grabbing hand" --- I want it to remain as a pointer. How do I do this? I have found various suggestions about modifying the CSS file or running Javascript or JQuery but I haven't been successful in getting these to work in R. Thanks.

````
---
title: "Leaflet Reprex"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
library(leaflet) 

my <- reactiveValues(long=175.619105, lat=-40.386396)
v <- reactiveValues(zoom=5, minzoom=5, maxzoom=15, long=NA, lat=NA) 

isolate({
  cat(file=stderr(), paste("initialise location"), "\n")
  v$long <- my$long
  v$lat <- my$lat
})

#### make initial map ####
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  cat(file=stderr(), paste("render leaflet"), "\n")

    isolate({ # prevent redraw if arguments change

      leaflet(options=leafletOptions(minZoom=v$minzoom, maxZoom=v$maxzoom)) %>%
        setView(v$long, v$lat, zoom=v$zoom)  %>%
        addTiles() %>% # default map
        addMarkers(my$long, my$lat, "layer1", options=pathOptions(clickable=FALSE)) 

    })

  }) # end renderLeaflet

#### ui ####
shinyUI(fluidPage(
      leafletOutput("map", width="100%", height=480) # can manipulate size here
)) # end fluidPage

#### react to mouse clicks ####
observeEvent(input$map_click, {

  cat(file=stderr(), "\n")
  cat(file=stderr(), paste("observed map_click"), "\n")    

  click <- input$map_click
  my$long <- click$lng
  my$lat <- click$lat

  # mark map
  leafletProxy("map", deferUntilFlush=FALSE) %>%
    addMarkers(my$long, my$lat, "layer1", options=pathOptions(clickable=FALSE)) 

}) # end observe mouse click

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track! You can just add css before your leaflet chunk:

````
```{css, echo = FALSE}
.leaflet-container {
  cursor: auto !important;
}
```
````

I got the css from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27155304/8099834) and the chunk location from [this thread](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/732). If you're interested, the different cursor options are listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).

[image]

---

````
---
title: "Leaflet Reprex"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document 
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
.leaflet-container {
  cursor: auto !important;
}
```

```{r echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
library(leaflet) 

my <- reactiveValues(long=175.619105, lat=-40.386396)
v <- reactiveValues(zoom=5, minzoom=5, maxzoom=15, long=NA, lat=NA) 

isolate({
  cat(file=stderr(), paste("initialise location"), "\n")
  v$long <- my$long
  v$lat <- my$lat
})

#### make initial map ####
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  cat(file=stderr(), paste("render leaflet"), "\n")

    isolate({ # prevent redraw if arguments change

      leaflet(options=leafletOptions(minZoom=v$minzoom, maxZoom=v$maxzoom)) %>%
        setView(v$long, v$lat, zoom=v$zoom)  %>%
        addTiles() %>% # default map
        addMarkers(my$long, my$lat, "layer1", options=pathOptions(clickable=FALSE)) 

    })

  }) # end renderLeaflet

#### ui ####
shinyUI(fluidPage(
      leafletOutput("map", width="100%", height=480) # can manipulate size here
)) # end fluidPage

#### react to mouse clicks ####
observeEvent(input$map_click, {

  cat(file=stderr(), "\n")
  cat(file=stderr(), paste("observed map_click"), "\n")    

  click <- input$map_click
  my$long <- click$lng
  my$lat <- click$lat

  # mark map
  leafletProxy("map", deferUntilFlush=FALSE) %>%
    addMarkers(my$long, my$lat, "layer1", options=pathOptions(clickable=FALSE)) 

}) # end observe mouse click

```
````